# Facebook Share Dialog fails - the operation couldn’t be completed swift

Tags: swift, facebook

I am testing a on am iphone device, user is logged in facebook app.

In the `do, catch` block I get error `error is message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FacebookShare.ShareError error 0.) on line 895 in /Users/bogdanbarbulescu/Desktop/myStreet.com/myStreet.com/MessagesViewController.swift.`

I found another suggestion on [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/242):

```
   let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
   content.contentURL = URL(string: "https://developers.facebook.com")
   FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
```

However, I get error `Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKShareLinkContent'`. If click on on `FBSDKShareLinkContent()` and jump to definition, I do get to FBSDKSharingContent.h

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit
import FacebookShare
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

   class MessagesVC {

  func invitePeopleTapped() {

     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Some title", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let shareOnFacebook = UIAlertAction(title: "Share on Facebook", style: .default) { _ in

        let linkContent = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!, quote: "Discover & Talk ")

        let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: linkContent)
            shareDialog.mode = .native
            shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true

        shareDialog.completion = { result in
           print("the result is \(result)")
        }

        do {
            try shareDialog.show()
        } catch {
            printsNow(message: error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
     alertController.addAction(shareOnFacebook)
     self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  } //end invitePeopleTapped

 } //end class



Using Bolts (1.9.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.38.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.38.0)
Using FBSDKMessengerShareKit (1.3.2)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.38.0)
Using FacebookCore (0.5.0)
Using FacebookLogin (0.5.0)
Using FacebookShare (0.5.0)
Using Firebase (5.11.0)

Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.0)
Using GeoFire (3.0.0)
Using GoogleAppMeasurement (5.3.0)
Using GoogleUtilities (5.3.4)
Using Protobuf (3.6.1)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.901)
Using pop (1.0.10)

 Full trace trace
```

> 2018-11-11 09:38:12.238951+0000 myStreet.com[6129:1364819] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType
>   com.apple.social.facebook 2018-11-11 09:38:12.257468+0000
>   myStreet.com[6129:1364819] [core] SLComposeViewController
>   isAvailableForServiceType got serviceType com.apple.social.facebook
>   isAvailable 0 2018-11-11 09:38:12.295729+0000
>   myStreet.com[6129:1365297] [core] SLComposeViewController
>   _shareExtensionWithIdentifier: continuous discovery block got extensions (
>       " {id = com.apple.share.SinaWeibo.post}",
>       " {id = com.apple.share.TencentWeibo.post}",
>       " {id = com.apple.share.Facebook.post}",
>       " {id = com.apple.share.Vimeo.post}",
>       " {id = com.apple.Music.MediaSocialShareService}",
>       " {id = com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService}",
>       " {id = com.apple.Health.HealthShareExtension}",
>       " {id = com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension}",
>       " {id = com.apple.share.Flickr.post}",
>       " {id = com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension}",
>       " {id = com.apple.share.Twitter.post}",
>       " {id = net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension}" ) error (null) 2018-11-11
>   09:38:12.296845+0000 myStreet.com[6129:1365297] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController _shareExtensionWithIdentifier: continuous
>   discovery block did update _identifierToShareExtensionMap {
>       "com.apple.Health.HealthShareExtension" = " {id = com.apple.Health.HealthShareExtension}";
>       "com.apple.Music.MediaSocialShareService" = " {id = com.apple.Music.MediaSocialShareService}";
>       "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension" = " {id = com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension}";
>       "com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService" = " {id = com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService}";
>       "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension" = " {id = com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension}";
>       "com.apple.share.Facebook.post" = " {id = com.apple.share.Facebook.post}";
>       "com.apple.share.Flickr.post" = " {id = com.apple.share.Flickr.post}";
>       "com.apple.share.SinaWeibo.post" = " {id = com.apple.share.Facebook.post} for
>   extensionIdentifer com.apple.share.Facebook.post 2018-11-11
>   09:38:12.298926+0000 myStreet.com[6129:1364819] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType returning YES for
>   overridden extensionIdentifier com.apple.share.Facebook.post
>   2018-11-11 09:38:12.298988+0000 myStreet.com[6129:1364819] [core]
>   SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType
>   com.apple.social.facebook returning 1 error is message: The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (FacebookShare.ShareError error 0.) on line 895
>   in
>   /Users/bogdanbarbulescu/Desktop/myStreet.com/myStreet.com/MessagesViewController.swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your'e missing the library

```
import FBSDKShareKit
```

for this code to work

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = URL(string: "https://developers.facebook.com")
FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
```